# C# How to get the length of chars in a string

Tags: c#, string

I have a `[]string retry`  and I have some strings inside of it let's say:
a 2 , a 3 , h 9, asd 123 and so on. They all have intervals between the letter and the integer. Now I need to get how long is the letter part (in this case "qwe 2" the letter length is 3 and the integer part is 2). I'm later using .substring from the specified index at which the letter part finishes and the integer one starts.

```
string[] s = new string[5];
List<string> retry = new List<string>();
int max = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
{
    s[i] = Console.ReadLine();
}

Console.WriteLine(" ");
Array.Sort(s);

for (int j = 0; j < s.Length; j++)
{
    if (j > 0)
    {
        if (s[j] == s[j - 1])
        {
            max++;

            if (retry.Any(x => x.Contains(s[j])))
            {
                retry.Add(s[j] + " " + max);
            }
            else
            {
                if (j <= s.Length - 1)
                {
                    if (s[j-1] != s[j])
                    {
                        retry.Add(s[j] + " " + max);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        retry.Add(s[j] + " " + max);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            max = 1;
        }
    }
}

for (int j = 0; j < retry.ToArray().Length; j++)
{
    for (int k = j + 1; k < retry.ToArray().Length; k++)
    {
        var a1=retry[j].Substring(0,1);
        var a2 = retry[k].Substring(0,1);

        if(a1==a2)
        {
            var b1 = retry[j].Substring(2);
            var b2 = retry[k].Substring(2);

            if(int.Parse(b1)>int.Parse(b2))
            {
                retry.Remove(a2 + " "+ b2);
            }
            else
            {
                retry.Remove(a1 + " " + b1);
            }
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(retry[j]);
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

This only works for 1 letter.

Comment: What's the end game here?  It sounds like a problem that's pretty trivially solved with a regular expression.

Comment: Split instead of taking a substring.

Comment: yes it's not even a solution just wanted to show you what i want to achieve but with some integer as a starting point and this integer will depend on the length of the chars

Comment: Did you, I don't know, look at the [String class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) to see if had methods that might help?  If so, did you read down as far as the methods starting with S?

Comment: It would also help to actually see in code what `retry` actually looks like

Comment: i will update the question with my full code

Comment: @Assim Is this what you want ? https://dotnetfiddle.net/mDZgyL

Comment: The code you posted in your revised question does a lot of stuff, very little of it relevant to your question.  In fact, it is hard to tell what part of that code _is_ relevant to your question.  Why not try coming up with a minimal example, as per [this advice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  And while you're at it, read some of the other comments.  @KrishnaDhungana actually was good enough to answer what I believe to be your question.

Comment: split your code into functions and add comments for clarity. skip the `Console.Read` part as it is not necessary for reproduction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below should get the result as expected:

```
string [] entries =  {"xyz 1","q 2","poiuy 4"};
for(int i=0;i<entries.Length;i++)
{
    var parts = entries[i].Split(' ');
    var txtCount = parts[0].Length;
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1}", txtCount, parts[1]));
}
```

Comment: This actually answers the question correctly (as I understood the question, which I reckon had to read a few times)

Answer (score 1):

How about...

```
string[] test = new [] { "qwe 2", "a 2", "b 3", "asd 123" };

foreach (var s in test)
{
    var lastLetterIndex = Array.FindLastIndex(s.ToCharArray(), Char.IsLetter);
    var lastNumberIndex = Array.FindLastIndex(s.ToCharArray(), Char.IsNumber);
    Console.WriteLine(s);
    Console.WriteLine("Letter Length : " + (lastLetterIndex + 1));
    Console.WriteLine("Number Length : " + (lastNumberIndex - lastLetterIndex));
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Uhm, from what I understand on the requirements, he wants the length of the letters (that part is right in the answer), but directly the number on the end, not the "length of the number + space(s) part"

Answer (score 0):

This iterates through all of the strings and counts the length of the chars, and stores the value of the number, as well as its index. Note that this information is lost upon each iteration, but I'll leave it to you to worry about storing that if you need that information for longer than the duration of an iteration.

```
int letterLength = 0, number = 0, index = 0;
string[] testString = { "a 2", "a 3", "h 9", "asd 123", "sw", "swa23", "swag 2464" };

foreach (string str in testString)
{
    letterLength = 0;
    index = -1;
    int i = 0;

    for (; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        char c = str[i];
        if (Char.IsLetter(c)) letterLength++;
        else if (Char.IsNumber(c)) break;
    }

    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    for (; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        char c = str[i];

        if (index == -1) index  = str.IndexOf(c);
        strBuilder.Append(c);

        number = Int32.Parse(strBuilder.ToString());
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"String: {str}\nLetter Length: {letterLength} Number: {number} Index: {index}\n");
}
```

[image: Output]